# Как правильно использовать функции в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
print("Введите строку :")
a = input()

print ("Введите число : ")
b = int (input())

def func(a, b) :
   print (a * b)
func(a, b)
x = func(a, b)
print ("Длина : ", len(x))
```

Comment: А в чем ошибка? Мы должны сами догадаться? Не выводит длину? Выводит не длину, а высоту?

Comment: Как правильно использовать "len()" ?

Comment: В вашем коде `len` используется правильно.

Comment: Как правильно использовать len() написано в описании функции len(). Или в учебнике в главе по работе со строками, списками и т.п.

Comment: `def func(a, b) :
   return a * b`

Comment: @S. Nick Спасибо !

Comment: Ваша функция ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция `func()` ничего не возвращает, потому что единственная команда, которую она выполняет - вывод данных в консоль. Поэтому x будет иметь тип 'NoneType'. Чтобы исправить проблему вместо `print()` сделайте `return` вашего значения:

```py
def func(a, b):
    return a * b


print("Введите строку :")
a = input()

print("Введите число : ")
b = int(input())

func(a, b)
x = func(a, b)
print("Длина : ", len(x))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помог.